# Is it possible to avoid long relative import paths on Flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

Could you point me to an example of how to configure `Flow` so that I could just use the name of a file for imports instead of long relative paths ?. This implies that the name of my files in my entire working directory are **unique**.

example:

Directories

```
pages/components/foo.js
common/types/abc.js
```

Current import statements

```
import foo from "../../pages/components/foo"
import abc from "../common/types/abc"
```

Desired import statements

```
import foo from "foo"
import abc from "abc"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very possible. But first hopefully you're setup your bundling tool to also accept parsing absolute path names because remember that flow does not handle logic it simply does code analysis but would throw errors if you haven't setup the pathing in `.flowconfig` and flow has no idea how to do a file lookup.

The option you're looking for is [module.name_mapper](https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-module-name-mapper-regex-string) which will repoint your written import into something else based on an **ocaml** regex.

If you are using create react app or have a setup similar for example you can see the [adding flow](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-flow/) section to see an example of how they've recommended handling it.

Comment: Do I need to add one line for each file I want to map? or is there a way to write a single line to lookup in the entire directory and map it to just the file name?

Comment: never mind, it looks like I can use capturing groups to get the filename and then use it as the template. thanks for the links :)